# Mean function returning INF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a df below as:

```
views | stats 
40       55
96       162
3         3
71        79
```

I then use following code below to create a new column that calcuates divison

```
df['calc'] = (df['stats'] / df['views']).round(0)
```

this gives me

```
  views | stats  | calc
    40       55   1.0
    96       162  1.0
    3         3   1.0
    71        79  1.0
    11        22  2.0
```

When I run a group by on the stats columns as below it works fine as:

```
df.groupby(['day','group'])['stats'].mean().reset_index().sort_values(by=['day','stats'], ascending = False)
```

**But** - when I run a group off of the new calc column as:

```
df.groupby(['day','group'])['calc'].mean().reset_index().sort_values(by=['day','calc'], ascending = False)
```

where day and group are other columns in the df that are text values that i want to group by

My output gives me some inf values as the mean value for stats which I dont understand.

The data types for my columns are:

**int64 for the views and stats column and
**float64 for the calc column****

I tried converting the calc column to int by doing below:

```
df['calc'] = df['calc'].apply(np.int64)
```

**But get an error that says: OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer**

How can I remedy this so I can not get inf as mean value for calc column?

Thanks

Comment: share a snippet with day & group

Comment: There might be `nan` in your data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have `np.inf` or `-np.inf` in your `calc` column. You can replace this infinity to NaN and convert the column to `Int64` (note the capital `I`):

```
df['calc'] = df['calc'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).astype('Int64')
print(df)
```

Prints (for example):

```
   views  stats  calc
0     40     55     1
1      0    162  <NA>
2      3      3     1
3     71     79     1
```